# Parsing a CSV in Node

Tags: node.js, csv

I am new to Node and struggling with what seems like a basic task. I want to read a sample CSV file into node and then sort columns into objects based on headers. I have looked into all the standard packages (YA-CSV, Fast-CSV, etc) but am really struggling with this.

If my csv is just:

```
A, B, C
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
```

I would like to import the file in Node, and sort the data into three objects as follows:

```
{"A": [1, 4]}
{"B": [2, 5]}
{"C": [3, 6]}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Those aren't valid objects. What do you actually want here? `{ "A": [ 1, 4 ] }`?

Comment: Thanks, I accidentally omitted the brackets

Comment: What does the data your CSV reader produces look like?

Comment: Numbers only data or are there strings?

Comment: Strings and numbers present in the data. Headers are all strings.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get a line
2. Explode with ","
3. Create object
4. Go Next line
   Repeat from 1 until eof

Comment: Step 2 is extremely naive. CSV allows for quoted strings.